# Connection from a BIDI to a uni SFP

Tags: fiber, sfp

I have to set up a connection from a BIDI SFP to a unidirectional SFP. Any idea how this i even possible? is there an intermediary device that can aggregate the Tx and Rx of one fibre and output only into one line?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: NO

The bidirectional (single wire) SFPs come in pairs because they use different frequencies in each direction. Even if you did split the fiber, the TX and RX wavelengths would (a) be different, and (b) not likely to conform to any standard SR/LR optics.  You'll need some form of "media converter" (aka: two port switch) that can take the matching SFP and convert it to whatever standard you want.

Comment: BX SFPs do commonly use "normal" frequencies - has to do with "normal" laser availability. 1310/1490 and 1310/1550 are typical BX singlemode setups, for instance. But I agree that it's a fool's errand to try and connect them directly, so +1 - of course, you don't need a media converter, since if you have the matching BX SFP you just remove the dual-fiber SFP and insert the correct BX SFP and you are done.

Comment: Assuming it's an SFP. (there are plenty of devices with non-removable optics)

Answer (score -2):

fiber is half duplex connection so one fiber core must be used as TX and other must used as a RX , SFP module must include both of them at the same time and there is no way to use unidirectional SFP for TX or RX.